# How to combine 3D token embeddings into 2D vectors?

Tags: python, tokenize, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I have a set of strings that I am tokenizing. I am sending each string into the `word2vec` model in `gensim`. Say, if there are 100 tokens (e.g. 'I', 'ate', 'pizza', etc.), it is generating a 100 * 100 3D matrix (`list` of `list` in `python`). How is it possible to convert the generated 3D token embeddings in to a 2D vector?

I am sending this 3D into a model in `Tensorflow` library. I am doing the following,

`model.add(Embedding(max_features, 128, input_length=maxlen))`

Here max_features is the size of the token vector i.e. 100 and input_length is also the same.

But I am not sure If this is getting the job done. Is it the right way to convert 3D token embeddings in to 2D vectors? Ideally, I want to covert the embeddings into 2D vectors before sending into the model.

Comment: to the best of my knowledge, the word2vec returns the vector (a python list) for each word. If you have a sentence you will have a list of list. To pass it on to the model, You can generate a sentence vector(the average of all the words vector) and pass it on to the model, this will work in cases where you have unique distinction for the words in the sentences which you want to classify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final results of training aren't really "3D" in usual `Word2Vec`/`gensim` terminology. If you've used `Word2Vec` with its default `vector_size=100`, and you had 100 vocabulary words, then you'd have 100 vectors of 100-dimensions each.

(Note: you would never want to create such high-dimensional "dense embedding" vectors for such a tiny vocabulary. The essential benefits of such dense representations come from forcing a much-larger set of entities into many-fewer dimensions, so that they are "compressed" into subtle, continuous, meaningful relative positions against each other. Giving 100 words a full 100 continuous dimensions, before `Word2Vec` training, will leave the model prone to severe overfitting. It could in fact then trend towards a "one-hot"-like encoding of each word, and become very good at the training task without really learning to pack related words near each other in a shared space – which is the usually-desired result of training. In my experience, for 100-dimension vectors, you probably want at least a 100^2 count of vocabulary words. If you really just care about 100 words, then you'd want to use much-smaller vectors – but also remember `Word2Vec` & related techniques are really meant for "large data" problems, with many subtly-varied training examples, and just barely sometimes give meaningful results on toy-sized data.)

The 100 vectors of 100-dimensions each are internally stored inside the `Word2Vec` model (& related components) as a raw `numpy` `ndarray`, which could be thought of as a "2d array" or "2d matrix". (It's not really a `list` of `list` unless you convert it to be that less-optimal form – though of course with Pythonic polymorphism you can generally pretend it was a `list` of `list`). If your `gensim` `Word2Vec` model is in `w2v_model`, then the raw `numpy` array of learned vectors is inside the `w2v_model.wv.vectors` property, though the interpretation of which row corresponds to which word-token depends on the `w2v_model.wv.vocab` dictionary entries.

As far as I can tell, the Tensorflow `Embedding` class is for training your own embeddings inside TF (though perhaps it can be initialized with vectors trained elsewhere). Its 1st initialization argument should the size-of-the-vocabulary (per your conjectured case 100), its second is the size-of-the-desired-embeddings (per your conjectured case, also 100 - but as noted above, this match of vocab-size and dense-embedding-size is inappropriate, and [the example values in the TF docs of 1000 words and 64 dimensions](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding) would be more appropriately balanced).

Comment: Thanks much! My vocabulary size is just 676. How can I set the size in `Word2Vec` for this size of vocab? Say if I have 100 tokens for each row, can I set the size to 26 (`sqrt(676)`) and get 100*26 vectors?

Comment: 626 tokens is a very small vocabulary for Word2Vec. The gensim `Word2Vec` class has an initialization parameter `size` for setting the vector dimensionality. Sizes that are a multiple of 4 are usually used – that might be a little faster in the underlying bulk vector routines. I'm not sure what you mean by "100 tokens for each row". (`Word2Vec` trains on variable-length texts, not fixed-length rows. But then each word-token gets a fixed-length vector.)

Comment: when I send tokens into `word2vec` I send tokens the size of 100 i.e. ['hello', ":", 'welcome', ... etc.] size of this list is 100. Each list is a row. But I am curious, if the vocabulary is very small, what is the size that we need to set. initial size is 100 in `word2vec`. Can I change the size to fit my vocabulary size? which is 676

Comment: OK, if you happen to split things into 100-token texts because that's convenient or fits your corpus. Just know that's not necessary or typical. (Usually, the texts are sent in their natural format: a sentence at a time, or a paragraph at a time, or a full post/article/record at a time, whatever.) The size that's set is the desired size of the final per-word vectors. So if you want 32-dimensional vectors, you supply `size=32` in the `Word2Vec` constructor parameters. As explained above, dimensionalities that are **much** smaller than the count of unique vocabulary words make the most sense.